# SET a variable into DQL query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

- I want to set a variable into a DQL query on the basis of condition
- case when both varibale value are matches the set variable rank.

dql query

```
 $q=$this->em->createQuery("select distinct u.id,u.city,u.country,u.designation FROM Entities\User u JOIN Entities\EventVisitor evt_vstr WITH evt_vstr.user = u.id WHERE (
                           CASE
                            WHEN $a =u.designation THEN SET @rank=1
                            WHEN $b =u.country THEN SET @rank=2
                            WHEN $c =u.city THEN SET @rank=3
                            WHEN $d =u.company THEN @rank=4
                            END) order by @rank")


                             ->setFirstResult($i)
                             ->setMaxResults($max_result);
                              $results = $q->getResult();
```

Here rank is the variable i am trying to set

problem im facing

- im unable to set  variable in dql .

errorlog

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException' with message 'select distinct u.id, u.city,u.country,u.designation FROM Entities\\User u JOIN Entities\\EventVisitor evt_vstr WITH evt_vstr.user = u.id \n\t \t\t\t\t\tWHERE (\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCASE\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWHEN Co-founder =u.designation THEN SET @rank=1\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEND   ) ' in /home/india/public_html/serve-trade-com/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39\nStack
```

But its not working.

How can i do that ?

OR is there any way to do that

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think that's possible in DQL, but you can use just plain SQL with Doctrine. take a look at the [`createNativeQuery` function](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html).

If you want to use it with an Symfony2 Entity, you should also take a look at the `Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping` class, which is used to create proper Entities out of the result.

Hope this helps.

Btw. In my opinion you shouldn't use PHP variables in your DQL string, but instead work with parameters, you can read about them [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query).

Comment: *"Unfortunately I don't think that's possible in DQL"* Pretty sure it is but it is long way around [Extending DQL in Doctrine 2: Custom AST Walkers](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html#extending-dql-in-doctrine-2-custom-ast-walkers), topicstarter indeed should simply use NativeQuery

Comment: Agreed, it's not possible out of the box ;)